# How to daisy chain threads using channels in Rust?

Tags: rust, coroutine, channel

I'm trying to implement the sieve of Eratosthenes in Rust using coroutines as a learning exercise (not homework), and I can't find any reasonable way of connecting each thread to the `Receiver` and `Sender` ends of two different channels.

The `Receiver` is involved in two distinct tasks, namely reporting the highest prime found so far, and supplying further candidate primes for the filter. This is fundamental to the algorithm.

Here is what I would like to do but can't because the Receiver cannot be transferred between threads. Using `std::sync::Arc` does not appear to help, unsurprisingly.

*Please note that I do understand why this doesn't work*

```
fn main() {
    let (basetx, baserx): (Sender<u32>, Receiver<u32>) = channel();
    let max_number = 103;
    thread::spawn(move|| {
        generate_natural_numbers(&basetx, max_number);
    });
    let oldrx = &baserx;
    loop {
        // we need the prime in this thread
        let prime = match oldrx.recv() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => { break; 0 }
        };
        println!("{}",prime);
        // create (newtx, newrx) in a deliberately unspecified way
        // now we need to pass the receiver off to the sieve thread
        thread::spawn(move || {
            sieve(oldrx, newtx, prime); // forwards numbers if not divisible by prime
        });
        oldrx = newrx;
    }
}
```

Equivalent working Go code:

```
func main() {
        channel := make(chan int)
        var ok bool = true;
        var prime int = 0;
        go generate(channel, 103)
        for true {
                prime, ok = <- channel
                if !ok {
                        break;
                }
                new_channel := make(chan int)
                go sieve(channel, new, prime)
                channel = new_channel
                fmt.Println(prime)
        }
}
```

What is the best way to deal with a situation like this where a `Receiver` needs to be handed off to a different thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really explain what the problem that you are having, but your code is close enough:

```
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender, Receiver};
use std::thread;

fn generate_numbers(tx: Sender<u8>) {
    for i in 2..100 {
        tx.send(i).unwrap();
    }
}

fn filter(rx: Receiver<u8>, tx: Sender<u8>, val: u8) {
    for v in rx {
        if v % val != 0 {
            tx.send(v).unwrap();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let (base_tx, base_rx) = channel();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        generate_numbers(base_tx);
    });

    let mut old_rx = base_rx;

    loop {
        let num = match old_rx.recv() {
            Ok(v) => v,
            Err(_) => break,
        };

        println!("prime: {}", num);

        let (new_tx, new_rx) = channel();

        thread::spawn(move || {
            filter(old_rx, new_tx, num);
        });

        old_rx = new_rx;
    }
}
```

> using coroutines

*Danger, Danger, Will Robinson!* These are **not** coroutines; they are full-fledged threads! These are a lot more heavyweight compared to a coroutine.

> What is the best way to deal with a situation like this where a `Receiver` needs to be handed off to a different thread?

Just... transfer ownership of the `Receiver` to the thread?